# Json Data in dialog and not activity

Tags: android, json, dialog

I was just wondering if its possible to show the response of webservice, a json formated, to a  custom dialog, example opening hours of a restaurant?

The problem is I have a listview and onClicklistener, it opens new activity and there I parsing data from webservice. inside the activity is a button where I getting hours from again from webservice. So I was wondering instead of opening new activity for hours, its possible to pars the json data to custom dialog/alert or sth like this? instead of a new activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, no. A `Dialog` needs an `Activity`. What you can do is create an `Activity` and give it a `Dialog Theme`. All you have to do is add

```
      @android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

to your `<activity>` tag in your `manifest`. This will give the look of a `Dialog` with the functionality of an `Activity`

Comment: thats true. but is there way to resize or make it fit 50% of the screen?

Comment: You can size the `layout` of it however you like. I haven't tried because anytime I use this, which is quite a bit, it works out nicely. I believe you can use `getWindow()` or something similar. I would have to look it up or see if I can find where I do it

Comment: [Here is a SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions) that talks about it if that's what you mean. That post is a little old and it seems like there's a better way of doing it but I will have to look

Comment: well thank you, I was using already Sherlock Actionbar and the one in libary is auto fitting, So I figure it out there. Well thank you very much for letting me know about Theme.Dialog. I have really forgotten about it.